# jQuery if div contains text, toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, togglebutton

I'm trying to get a button to be toggled if a div contains a string of text. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
if ('$div#trackingnumber:contains('Hello')');') {
    $("dinput#submitam").toggle()});
}
});
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: a call of $() will always return an object, no matter if the selector matches anything, so a boolean comparision is useless there(an object is never false). You need to check the length of the result (like suggested by dknaack) to determine if the result was empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right way. I only see some syntax errors. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($("#trackingnumber:contains('Hello')").length != 0) 
     {
         $("dinput#submitam").toggle();
     }
});
```

#### Checkout this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPpXH/1/) too.

Comment: For some reason, instead of toggling the button, it is hiding it, do you know why? It's adding `style="display:none;"` to it.

Comment: Not without more information. Could you post some more source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("div#trackingnumber:contains('Hello')").length > 0)
  $("dinput#submitam").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $("#trackingnumber:contains('Hello')").length > 0 ) {
        $("#submitam").toggle();
    }
});
```